# CsvReader Error: Header matching ['ID'] names at index 0 was not found

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to read a simple CSV file using CsvReader 6.1.1 but keep getting this error:

Header matching ['ID'] names at index 0 was not found.

Here's the CSV file:

```
"ID","FirstName","LastName","JobTitle","Department","Email"
"1","Necole","Moore","Program Manager ","Housing & Supportive Services","MooreN@AFHouston.org"
```

Here's the C# code I'm using:

```
Stream stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
        var records = csv.GetRecords<CRIContactModel>();
        foreach(var record in records) //***Fails here***
        {
            var contact = _criContactService.FindAsync(x => x.ID == record.ID);
            if (contact != null)
            {
                _criContactService.Update(record, record.ID);
            }
            else
            {
                _criContactService.Add(record);
            }
        }
```

Here's the CRIContactModel class:

```
public class CRIContactModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate any ideas on what the issue could be.

Comment: Show `CRIContactModel` class definition

Comment: @Nkosi I just added it above.

Comment: `ID` is an `int` in the class but a `string` in the data

Comment: I removed the double quotes around the 1 in the CSV file but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Not sure which framework you are using. look into this https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading#getting-all-records

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got this error, because i used a different delimiter in my csv files as the CsvHelper expected. After changing the configuration bevore reading everything worked as expected `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";`.

Full Example:

```
Stream stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
var records = csv.GetRecords<CRIContactModel>();
foreach(var record in records) {
    var contact = _criContactService.FindAsync(x => x.ID == record.ID);
    if (contact != null) {
        _criContactService.Update(record, record.ID);
    }
    else {
        _criContactService.Add(record);
    }
}
```